# WPF Combobox, SelectedItem object re-created out of ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have an issue with a combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DimensionsCollection}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding CGEM.Dimension,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Name="cb_Dimensions" 
          Width="140" Height="30" Foreground="Gray">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="Dimension">
               <TextBlock Background="Transparent" 
                          Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The DimensionsCollection, is build in my ViewModel from an xml config file.

When i select a dimension by the combobox, my "CGEM.Dimension" is well updated.

The problem is in the other way...

I can save my CGEMs in an XML file, to reload it later. When i recreate the dimension object (with XmlSerialiser), the combobox is not uptdated...

The only way to reupdate the combobox is to replace the "CGEM.Dimension", by the corresponding one in the collection... Not realy clean solution...

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofb.FileName))
{
     CGEMModel CGEMLoaded=(xs.Deserialize(sr) as CGEMModel);
     /* this line should be enough...*/
     this.CGEM = CGEMLoaded; 
     this.CGEM.Dimension = DimensionsCollection.Where(
          d => d.DisplayName == CGEMLoaded.Dimension.DisplayName
          ).First();         
}
```

I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in all objects...
Is there an other way to do that ? A cleaner way, which would allow me to erase the dirty linq line ? (I need one line like that by property...)

Comment: "Not realy clean solution" Maybe in your opinion. However, the only working solution as long as you want to use SelectedItem. You may instead try SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath.

Comment: Besides that you may shorten your LINQ expression to `DimensionsCollection.First(d => d.DisplayName == CGEMLoaded.Dimension.DisplayName)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution :

I have to override the Equals(object obj) method of all my objects...

It is enough to solve the problem.
To my mind it is because the combobox was not able to find the correct object in the collection because it do not had a reference to compare an object with another.

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.DisplayName==(obj as Dimension).DisplayName;
    }
```